# Conditional Formatting/Colors in Sparklines in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, average, ssrs-2012, sparklines

I've looked at several websites that all suggest going into Chart Data > Values, and then right-clicking to change the formula of the Fill Color attribute to a formula that defines how I want the color scheme to look, but I tried that already, and I don't get back what I anticipated.

My data (e.g., Fields!DailySalesGoalPassFail.Value) is aggregated in the Sparkline by Avg, and categorized by EntryDate. If a single location is selected, each of the Pass/Fail values will be either "1" or "0" for any given EntryDate, but if multiple locations are selected, I want the Pass/Fail to be able to return something in-between (for instance, ".5" if 1 of 2 stores in the group pass).

Furthermore, I want to be able to color the nodes of the Sparkline green if it's =1, red if =0, and yellow if it's somewhere between, but every time I try to write a Switch statement to handle that and the starting value is 0, then the whole line is red, even if the value later climbs above 0.

```
=Switch(
        Fields!DailySalesGoalPassFail.Value = 1, "Green",
        Fields!DailySalesGoalPassFail.Value = 0, "Red",
        true, "Yellow"
        )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `Switch()` depends on the wrong `Field`. Because your `Fields!DailySalesGoalPassFail.Value` is as you said aggregated by Avg and most likely a number. If your `Fields!DailySalesGoalPassFail.Value` has for example values from `1` to `100` this coloring will work at the fill expresssion:

```
=Switch(Fields!DailySalesGoalPassFail.Value < 50, "Green", 
        Fields!DailySalesGoalPassFail.Value > 50, "Red")
```

I think what you really want is to depend your sparkline on the pass/fail value. In this case you can write the following at the fill expression (I am not sure where your pass/fail value comes from. I am guessing its a parameter now):

```
=Switch(Parameters!PassFail.Value = 1, "Green",
        Parameters!PassFail.Value = 0, "Red",
        Parameters!PassFail.Value < 1 And Parameters!PassFail.Value > 0, "Yellow")
```

Comment: I switched it to using the Avg aggregate, rather than the Field.Value, and that did it. Thanks for giving me a second pair of eyes.